# How can we block any user from deleting a record in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, user, permission-sets, delete

I have delete button on the visualforce page. If particular record status moved out of 'Draft' then the record should not be deleted. If user clicks on delete button with the status value 'Open', it should not allow any user to delete the record.

I've already done this in sandbox and pushed to prod. After some days, some users are able to delete the record eventhough the status of the record is moved out of 'Draft'. But if I try to reproduce the problem in sandbox by logging in as a user who deleted the record in production is not able to delete the record.

Then I checked all the security informations(user, profile, permission set, apex code) everything is same as that of in production.

So my question is,

**Then how would the user was able to delete the record in Production?**.

Also, Is there any way to block any users to delete the record(bypassing everything)?.

Comment: Can you hide the button based on the RecordStatus?

Comment: @unidha This is a good idea. We planned to hide the button based on the status field. But I want to know how the users deleted the record in production.

Comment: @MuzammilBajaria Yes it is custom visualforce page with controller extension

Comment: Not sure.Is the controller class without sharing? Other way for you to check if user able to delete is using DescribeObject isDeletable() .

Comment: @unidha The Controller class is with sharing. But sharing rules are same in both sandbox and production

Comment: Could they have deleted it outside of the VF page using the standard delete button?

Comment: @Eric No, because we are redirecting every record to visualforce page. So there is no possibility of opening the standard layout and deleting it.

Comment: It is possible to bypass page overrides and get the standard layout using the &nooveride=1 parameter - generally normal users don't know how to do this, but don't rule it out

Comment: Does your code prevent them from editing an "Open" record and changing it back to "Draft" ?

Answer (score 1):

Overriding with a Visualforce page only partially protects a record. There are still ways around this UI "protection", such as by using a mobile device, using some sort of tool that uses the API, and so on. What you really need to do is to protect it at the business logic level by implementing a trigger:

```
trigger preventDelete on Contract (before delete) {
    for(someSObject record: Trigger.old) {
        if(record.Status != 'Draft') {
            record.addError('You may not delete a non-draft contract.');
        }
    }
}
```

You can build in different logic as needed, such as still allowing administrators to perform deletions, etc.